# I am getting a validation error from http://validator.w3.org "there is no attribute href"

Tags: html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/North-Carolina-Military-Foundation/101762603238869" send="true" layout="button_count" width="auto" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
```

I am getting a validation error from http://validator.w3.org as "there is no attribute "href, send, latout, width, show_faces and font"? is there any solution ?

Comment: "is there any solution?" Yes - use correct markup. `<fb>` is not a valid tag in XHTML

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a "Like" button on your html head over
    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Fill the form and it will generate the correct code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare namespace.

e.g.

```
<xhtml xmlns:fb="fb:http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" >
<body>
 <fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/North-Carolina-Military-Foundation/101762603238869" send="true" layout="button_count" width="auto" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>
</body>
</xhtml>
```